# php Date explanation please (going back in week blocks)

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a mysql database with a table called logs. In this table are logs of items scanned out from the warehouse.

I need to pull some data from the database via php to make a graph of weekly scanned volume of each item.

e.g.
One product is called DD2 and I would like to pull:

1. How many DD2's were scanned in the last 7 days (including today so today + the previous 6 days).
2. How many DD2's were scanned in the previous week.
3. How many DD2's were scanned in the week before that (week -3)
4. How many DD2's were scanned in the week before that (week -4)
   etc etc for 10 weeks.

I have the following SQL

```
"
SELECT SUM(stock_removed) as total 
FROM logs 
WHERE (model_number = 'DD2' 
AND time BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 DAY ) 
AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL -1 DAY ) )
";
```

Now I think this is doing the past 7 days *including* today.

So today being the 7-Nov-2020 I think it is pulling data that have the date timestamp of:

```
7-Nov-2020
6-Nov-2020
5-Nov-2020
4-Nov-2020
3-Nov-2020
2-Nov-2020
1-Nov-2020
```

(Please correct me if I'm wrong)

If I am right, to do the weeks before, would I do?:

```
"
SELECT SUM(stock_removed) as total 
FROM logs 
WHERE (model_number = 'DD2' 
AND time BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 13 DAY ) 
AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 DAY ) )
";
```

So would that do the dates:

```
31-Oct-2020
30-Oct-2020
29-Oct-2020
28-Oct-2020
27-Oct-2020
26-Oct-2020
25-Oct-2020
```

OR would the above also include the 1-nov e.g.

```
1-Nov-2020
31-Oct-2020
30-Oct-2020
29-Oct-2020
28-Oct-2020
27-Oct-2020
26-Oct-2020
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See CASE...WHEN.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Actually, if each bucket is the same size (1 week), then CASE ... WHEN is unnecessary. Ignore that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have linked the above. A data set for a database with three columns (Primary key, time, model_number) is a bit overkill. The question above is more asking if the provided coding includes or excludes the 1st Nov e.g. the 7th day back.

Comment: In which case I suggest you downvote nbk's answer, which does exactly that.

Comment: We only wish that more askers would embrace Strawberry's meta page.  Providing a [mcve] is actually spelled out as a requirement at [ask].  This component of a complete question is not to making asking harder, it is to make answering easier and allow others to simply verify that answers are or are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a little formula to compute how many weeks ago a particular `time` occurred, as an integer.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(time)) DIV 7
```

That's a handy formula

Next, let's write a little query to fetch your `logs` with an extra `weeks_ago` column.

```
     SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(time)) DIV 7 weeks_ago, *
       FROM logs
```

Next, let's use that as a subquery

```
SELECT weeksago, SUM(stock_removed) as total 
FROM (
          SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(time)) DIV 7 weeks_ago, *
           FROM logs
 ) logsw
WHERE model_number = 'DD2' 
  AND time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 WEEK + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC
```

The trick here is to get yourself something you can use in GROUP BY.  The subquery gives you a virtual table with that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can gather all data, by Group ping, and so you could also get data for more than 1
item

> ```
> CREATE TABLE stock (stock_removed int,model_number  VARCHAR(5),`time` Date);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO stock VALUES (1,'DD2','2020-11-07'),(1,'DD2','2020-11-06'),(1,'DD2','2020-11-05'),(1,'DD2','2020-11-04')
> ,(1,'DD2','2020-11-03'),(1,'DD2','2020-11-02'),(1,'DD2','2020-11-01'),
> (2,'DD2','2020-10-31'),(2,'DD2','2020-10-30'),(2,'DD2','2020-10-29'),(2,'DD2','2020-10-28')
> ,(2,'DD2','2020-10-27'),(2,'DD2','2020-10-26'),(2,'DD2','2020-10-25'),
> (3,'DD2','2020-10-24'),(3,'DD2','2020-10-23'),(3,'DD2','2020-10-22'),(3,'DD2','2020-10-21')
> ,(3,'DD2','2020-10-20'),(3,'DD2','2020-10-19'),(3,'DD2','2020-10-18'),
> (4,'DD2','2020-10-17'),(4,'DD2','2020-10-16'),(4,'DD2','2020-10-15'),(4,'DD2','2020-10-14')
> ,(4,'DD2','2020-10-13'),(4,'DD2','2020-10-12'),(4,'DD2','2020-10-11')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> model_number,
> SUM(
> CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND CURDATE() 
> THEN stock_removed ELSE 0 END
> ) sumlastweek,
> SUM(
> CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
> THEN stock_removed ELSE 0 END
> ) sumtwoweek
> ,
> SUM(
> CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
> THEN stock_removed ELSE 0 END
> ) sumthreeweek,
> SUM(
> CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 27 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY
> THEN stock_removed ELSE 0 END
> ) sumfourweek
> FROM stock
> WHERE model_number = 'DD2'
> GROUP BY model_number
> ```
>
> ```
> model_number | sumlastweek | sumtwoweek | sumthreeweek | sumfourweek
> :----------- | ----------: | ---------: | -----------: | ----------:
> DD2          |           7 |         14 |           21 |          28
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06e0e31ad5ded35277ec0bc141719b1a)*